# How to perfectly combine clips

Tags: transitions

Sorry if this is posted elsewhere, but I can't find it.

I'm a novice video editor. I videoed my niece's wedding. For some reason, my camera split the ceremony into 3 clips. I imported them into Premiere Pro 2015.2 (Creative Cloud) and added them to the timeline. It put them back to back to back. The problem is where it switches from one clip to the next, there's a small gap of silence noticeable in the audio (music is playing in both the spots, which compounds the problem) instead of smoothly transitioning from one clip to the next.

I've searched high and low and can't find a way to make the transition seamless (if that's even possible). Can anyone provide guidance? Remember, I'm a novice at this.

Thanks!
Kirby

Answer (score 1):

First, check to make sure that neither you nor the app have created handles on your clips. Handles are a few frames at the beginning and end of a clip that are used to overlap with another clip when doing a crossfade or other transition.

If you're sure that the in and out points of the clips really are the first and last frames of each clip, then you're probably out of luck. (See below for 1 possible solution.) Why does this happen? Without knowing the camera you used, I can only guess. There are 2 reasons that cameras will break clips into smaller pieces:

1. <strike>U.S.</strike>E.U. Tax Code - When importing a camera from another country, if the camera can record 30 minutes or more (I think - don't quote me on the exact time), then it is considered a video recorder and is taxed at a higher rate than a still camera. To skirt this issue and keep prices low, many low-end cameras will limit their record time to 1 frame less than the minimum required to be considered a video camera. Many will even automatically create multiple clips that are no longer than the limit. [Here's a link that explains it](http://www.tested.com/tech/photography/44445-why-digital-cameras-have-a-30-minute-video-recording-limit/)
2. File System Limits - Older file systems (particularly DOS's FAT file system which is used by lots of cameras) may have a maximum file size limit of either 2GB or 4GB, depending on the implementation. If your clips are long enough to be bigger than 2 or 4GB, some cameras will split the clip into multiple files automatically.

So it could be the camera auto-split for one of the above reasons. The thing is that some cameras will drop frames during the splitting of files, and when they do, there's nothing you can do to get them back. You might be able to create in-between frames using a tool like [Re:Vision FX Twixtor](http://revisionfx.com/products/twixtor/), or a similar product.